# Laptop Lid Options Not Showing Up in Power Manager After Installation

Tags: lubuntu

I would like to install Lubuntu 18.04 on my Dell Latitude D430 laptop.  However, I've noticed that, after installation, Power Manager doesn't show the same available options as it does when I run a live DVD.

If I pop in the Lubuntu 18.04 live DVD, and click Start > Preferences > Power Manager, Power Manager shows options for my laptop's lid, and how the operating system is expected to respond when I close it. Here's a screenshot of the options that it has:

[image: Lid Options Available screenshot]

However, after installation, when I go to Power Manager, the laptop lid options aren't available.  Here's a screenshot, of that, after installation:

[image: No Lid Options Available screenshot]

Ever since I installed Lubuntu 18.04 on my laptop, I've been unable to close my laptop lid without having to reboot the computer.  If I close the lid, and then open it, the screen is dark.  At that point, nothing will get me out of that mode -- not moving the mouse, pressing ctrl-alt-f1, nothing.  All I can do is reboot the computer.

I think that the fact that these options don't show up, is key to why this is happening.  I've tried many of the online suggestions about altering `/etc/systemd/login.conf`.  I've also tried the `gnome-tweak-tool` and installing `pm-utils`.  However, none of this works. I think it's because of this difference of what's available, after installation, versus what's available, in Power Manager, while running the live DVD.

If I run the live DVD, and close the lid to the laptop, the screen still goes dark.  However, I can get it back by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>, and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd>; which is what I used to do in Lubuntu 16.04.

If anyone can explain why the laptop lid option isn't showing up after installation, and has insight on how to fix this problem, I'd love to hear from you.

Comment: Are you aware that flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that is now EOL (*end-of-life*).  See https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/  https://lubuntu.me/bionic-5-released/ https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/  with support ending April-2021.   Use `ubuntu-support-status` on your system to confirm the supported/unsupported packages & act accordingly (ie. how important is security to you, are you offline etc?)

Comment: FYI:  XFCE was fully GTK2 like LXDE was in *xenial*; but XFCE was being ported to GTK3 during the *bionic* cycle so your power settings might be expected to have been different between those releases. You mention two LTS releases, where LTS have two stack choices, but you don't mention which you were using; again differences (six year differences if GA used on *xenial* & HWE used on *bionic*, but you do miss completely only hardware (no details) which is what I'd compare with your wanted software stack (also unstated); but sorry Lubuntu now only supports LXQt (not *deprecated GTK2/LXDE*)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guiverc.  I'm currently using Lubuntu 18.04.  I only switched from Lubuntu 16.04, due to the fact that my laptop is 32-bit, and can no longer work with major streaming platforms, like Netflix, Amazon Prime and Hulu.  I'm not that worried about security, since I primarily use my laptop to watch movies and shows.  For this reason, I haven't had to upgrade for a long time.

Comment: FYI: I realized you were i386; I used a `dell latitude d610 (pentium m, 1.5gb, intel i915)` for QA-testing releases up to Lubuntu 19.04 or when *i386* was dropped; last used for 18.04.5.  If you were using a *live* ISO that uses the HWE stack but wasn't the latest (18.04.5), post-install a different kernel (& stack) will be used which will mean it's different post-install; you didn't say if using a GA or HWE, ie. you weren't specific as to ISO/installed 18.04 system.  Did you consider that?  I had two boxes (old pentium M) that didn't like the 5.4/HWE stack but ran well on GA or up to 5.3/HWE

Comment: Upgrading to Lubuntu 19.04 may work.  However, I don't currently have access to a blank DVD.  I only have access to a Lubuntu 18.04 DVD.  I'm just surprised that the options, after installation, are different than that shown with a live DVD.

Comment: As my last comment stated; you didn't say which 18.04 media you used. The one (ISO) you use controls which stack is used by default of the two options available for LTS releases.  The initial media (18.04) & 18.04.1 default to GA stack or 4.15 kernel; later ISOs default to HWE stack (which will upgrade itself post-install if you're not on the latest)... ie. your kernel may have changed post-install if you used either of 3 18.04 ISOs (18.04.2 or 4.18, 18.04.3 or 5.0, 18.04.4 or 5.3) which was my point.  You gave no details as to your stack, or which of the 7 Lubuntu 18.04 ISOs you used.

Comment: I burned this DVD a long time ago.  When I put it into my drive, it only shows as 18.04.

Comment: `uname -r` will tell the kernel version, if you get a 4.15 result your ISO defaults to using the GA stack (it never changes, maximum stability), if you get 4.18 it was 18.04.2 media, 5.0 it was 18.04.3 media etc.. and it'll upgrade to get later kernel modules useful for newer hardware; ie. HWE or hardware enablement stack is used; thus a post-install system can boot into a different kernel to what was used in the initial *live* session...  It can be changed post-install, but ISO controls the initial *live* and installed version.  Your release though is EOL as per my first comment and Lubuntu.

Comment: `uname -r` yeilds `4.15.0-147-generic`, which makes this situation more peculiar.

Comment: Don't upgrade to 19.04 because it has even less support since it is a standard release.  At least the base of Ubuntu 18.04 is supported until 2023.  You may consider installing Ubuntu **Server** 18.04 and then trying to install LxQt on top of that.

Comment: Thanks, @Nmath.  I've been considering installing Debian, since that's what I've done with other computers whenever I run into a version of Lubuntu that doesn't work for me.  They, too, offer a way to install, and make it look like Lubuntu.  Debian also tends to be a bit more stable.  However, I've never installed it on my laptop.  Either way, thanks for the heads up about 19.04.